# Pure javascript solution to fix headlines hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, section508

In order to fix accessibility problems with headline hierarchy required for section 508 (Requirement 1194.22 (d)), I need to rewrite headlines hierarchy with JS.

Problem is that HTML is already built and that back-end technologies cannot be used to reorder those headlines. We have a situation that some headlines are of lower order than they are supposed to be, so they appear in this order, for example:

```
H1
  H2
    H4
    H4
    H4
H1
  H3
    H4
    H4
      H5
  H2
    H4
```

This should be converted to

```
H1
  H2
    H3
    H3
    H3
H1
  H2
    H3
    H3
      H4
  H2
    H3
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Accessibility used to require that `Javascript`  by disabled, is this no longer the case?

Comment: Screen readers can understand DOM that is changed by JS now. Where did you find requirement for javascript to be cosidered to be disabled by default?

Comment: I may be very out of date on the one. So ignore me :). The task you have here requires you to use `state` as you pass the document.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have to do anything.  There is nothing in 1194.22 that says the order of the headings must be sequential, although that is certainly the preference.

(Note that [Section 508 was updated](https://www.section508.gov/blog/accessibility-news-the-section-508-Update) a couple years back so that it follows WCAG 2.0 so referring to 1194.22(d) is old school and instead you should refer to WCAG 2.0.  In this particular case, [success criteria 1.3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html) talks about headings.)

It can be perfectly valid to have an <H4> nested under a <H2>.  Your tool cannot make the decision on whether the hierarchy is correct.  A human must do that.

Comment: Is it possible that hierarchy is not strictly tied in with the correct level of HTML headline tags, as long as they are of lower level than the parent headline?

Comment: Since headings are not containers, you can't really tell what the nesting level is.  You could have a main navigation at the top of the page with an <h2> and then have an <h1> for the main content.  Since the headings are "siblings" in the DOM, it's hard to tell if the hierarchy is correct or not.  (It **is** correct in this example.)

Answer (score 0):

When incorporating third party libraries, having bad heading hierarchy is a quite common problem, but in fact the main problem is that in many cases those heading should not exist. Getting rid of them should be considered before applying the following script which does the intended job.

This javascript uses jQuery but can be adapted in vanilla-javascript. It parses the page for standard headings (`h1` to `h6`) and changes the level to the appropriate expected level at the rank considering its parent one.

The difficulty of this kind of scripts is that in your example, fixing the heading hierarchy just by changing the first `h4` to a `h3` for instance might work on paper but is not a reliable solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var level=0, plevel=[0];
  $("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h5").each(function() {
    var c_level=$(this)[0].tagName.substr(1);
    var p_level=plevel[plevel.length-1];

    while (c_level<p_level) {
      plevel.pop();
      level--;
      p_level=plevel[plevel.length-1];
    }

    if (c_level>p_level) {
      level++;
      plevel.push(c_level);
    }

    if (c_level!=level) {
      $(this).replaceWith("<h"+(level)+">"+$(this).html()+"</h"+(level)+">");
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: what is p_level, plevel, level, c_level? I really want to like this solution but it's very ambiguous and hard to decipher and understand what this code does.

Comment: @DaveDogaOz "clevel" stands for "current level" and "plevel" for "previous level"